# Unable to display Report on Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, reporting

[image]I'm trying to display a report on my Visualforce but its not displaying the same. Please help

`My Page

```
 <apex:page >
    <apex:form> 
       <apex:iframe src="/00O90000007H9qR?isdtp=nv" width="100%"/>
    </apex:form>
 </apex:page>`
```

Comment: have you find the solution?

Answer (score 6):

With the Spring 14 release, you can now use the `<analytics>` tag to embed report charts in VF pages.

```
<apex:page>
     <analytics:reportChart reportId=”00Oxxxxxxxxxxxx”></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

Check out [here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_analytics_vf_charts.htm) for more info.

Also, a very good answer already posted ont his subject by Jesse Altman, worth checking out as well.

[reports embedded in visualforce not showing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33003/reports-embedded-in-visualforce-not-showing)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs. I used <analytics> tag to display the report but its not displaying the report on VF Page. However if Im adding a chart to the report, that chart is being displayed on page. I only need to display the report and not chart on my Page. Attaching the screenshot as well.

Comment: This code only shows charts, but how do you display the actual report?

Answer (score -3):

This code should work.

```
<apex:outputPanel >
    <script>
         location.href="/<RepordID>?isdtp=vw";
    </script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.... However this code is still not showing any report on VF Page