# Show reports in VisualForce Page through Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, profile, user

I want to generate reports in Visual Force through apex for a particular user. Does any one have a sample code or having any guiding tutorial to get start with this

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33003/reports-embedded-in-visualforce-not-showing/85676#85676