# Call a report with apex for Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, analytics

I would like create a visualforce page which call a custom report.
I find that it's possible for chart :

```
<apex:page>
<analytics:reportChart reportId=”00Oxxxxxxxxxxxx”></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

Is existing the same thing in order to load a custom report easily ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to embed a chart from an existing report into a Visualforce Page, here is an example from Salesforce documentation.

Just make sure
- API version is 29.0 or later. 
- Check that the source report has a chart in Salesforce.

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_analytics_vf_charts.htm

These attributes are supported. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm

update - 
@User30008,

I think embedding report data directly into VF page is not possible at this time. Also check out below thread for some workaround for a similar requirement.

[reports embedded in visualforce not showing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33003/reports-embedded-in-visualforce-not-showing/85676#85676)

Comment: I believe OP is looking to embed the report details/summary, not the visualization of the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, i don't want to load a chart, only a report. I would like only load the report and show the data (a table). We have different visualforce pages which work with the wiews like : <apex:enhancedList type="Lead" id="LeadList" listId="0xxxxxx" height="xx" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="xx"/> This is working very well. The visualforce page load the view and datas.
I would like do the same but with a report and load datas.
Do you think it is possible ? Or with a href ?